# How to take a string from another file in perl which contains a variable defined in former file

Tags: perl

I am not sure how to state the problem in sentences. Let me give a n instance:

There is one file

> abc.pl

it's contents are as follows:

```
use def;
my $log = $def::logs;
my $text = "this is the text to be searched with value123";

my $var = "value123";
my $findstring = $log->{'search'};
&find("$text","findstring ");
```

Now file def.pm, which is used in above file:

```
package def;
our $logs = {
             'search' => "text to be searched with $var"
};
```

in this file how should I give $var so that it is interpolated in file abc.pl and not in the same file?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you wish to pass the $ var into $logs and use it. One way is to implement $logs as a function i.e setLogs($var){$logs=$var}; Let me know if this answers your query

Comment: Actually in my case, def is a data file, which can contain only data. So I used a hash "$logs". and this hash has many such entries. The string value in this hash has to be in data file only with $var.

Comment: It's hard to tell, but it _sounds_ like what you want is [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html).

Comment: As Matt stated, sprintf can be used. In def file instead of $var, make it %s and when you get the hash value in abc.pl, sprintf it with $var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String are interoperated when they are defined.  In the case of a package being used this will happen at compile time.  What you will need to do is to ensure that the strings definition is delayed until after $var is set.

For example this is a way.

```
package Def;

use strict;

our $logs = {
   'search' => sub {
        my ($var) = @_;

        return "text to be search with $var";
   }
};
```

Then you can use it like this.

```
use def;
use strict;

my $log = $def::logs;
my $text = "this is the text to be searched with value123";

my $var = "value123";
my $findstring = $log->{'search'}->($var);

find($text, $findstring);
```